# PHP version 5.5 doesn't recognize custom include_path set in php.ini file. Lower PHP version does

Tags: php, include-path

My website currently runs on PHP 5.2 on an Apache Linux server (according to my hosting providers info). I want to upgrade to at least PHP 5.5 since there is a feature I need available from that version and above. I am open to also use higher versions like 7, but every version above 5.2 brings the following problem:

When running in PHP 5.2 I successfully added a custom include_path additionally to the default one in the php.ini

php.ini:

```
[PHP]
include_path = ".:/usr/local/lib/php:/custom/include/path"
register_globals = Off
```

In the above php.ini code the default path which was already set is

```
/usr/local/lib/php
```

and the one I added is

```
/custom/include/path
```

(I removed personal information by changing path and file names).

I should mention that the additional include_path is not in the same folder structure. In fact, it is on a different domain. Still the same server, but a different domain, so for the additional path I have to go through the root path of my providers users/... path.

(The domains share the same website content, just in different languages. That is why I want both to be able to access and process a common main include_path since they use the same scripts).

In my website I include php files commonly just like this:

website.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'external_script_file.php';
?>
```

As I said, in PHP 5.2 everything runs smoothly. The file is loaded and processed. But as soon as I switch the PHP version up to let's say 5.5 I get this error:

Error in browser:

```
Warning: require_once(external_script_file.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /[server_path]/website.php on line 7

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'external_script_file.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /[server_path]/website.php on line 7
```

(I removed personal information by changing path and file names).

As you see in the error message, he seems to only be able to see the default include path, but not the added custom one.

Do I have to manage something differently regarding the php.ini settings file when operating in a higher PHP version? Or what else could be the issue?

Thanks a lot!
​

Answer (score 0):

You can try using set_include_path() function in your code.

```
set_include_path('/usr/lib/pear');
```

Or ini_set()

```
ini_set('include_path', '/usr/lib/pear');
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried that and didn't work for me. Probably works in general, but not for my case, since I have to access an include_path of a different domain (but still on the same server). I added this information to the question after your post. thx

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mentioned any information about the system you are trying to run PHP on (i.e. what OS, web server, etc), so this is a shot in the dark. If you have multiple PHP versions installed, it's possible that each version has its own php.ini file.

On the page you are trying to load, stick `phpinfo();die;` at the top of the file. Run the site in PHP 5.2, and see what the "Loaded Configuration File" value is. Then, switch to a newer PHP version, refresh the page, and check if the "Loaded Configuration File" value is the same or not.

Comment: I added the server information. Good point. The phpinfo brought some interesting infos. For both PHP versions it loads the same custom php.ini file I set. (As soon as I rename or delete the php.ini file, the "Loaded Configuration File" changed to a default path of the server). So at least it seems like the ini file is recognized. But interestingly when I scroll down the phpinfo page, there is also the "include_path" value. At 5.2 there is my custom set path, but at 5.5 it isn't there. So apperently in 5.5 it still picks up the php.ini file, but not the include_path value which is in there.

Answer (score 0):

Just an accident!

Either the php.ini generator I used, or just me copying back and forth created a space at the beginning of the php.ini file, right before the title [PHP]. Apparently PHP versions higher than 5.2 can't handle that.

So just make sure to not create any unneccessary spaces within, or especially at the beginning of the php.ini file.